# Calling an anonymous function from an anonymous function

Tags: function, clojure, anonymous-function

I'd like to call an anonymous function which is *not* using the shorthand notation from another anonymous function.

Doing the following isn't working because the last evaluation is returned:

```
user> ((fn [x] (fn [y] (inc y)) x) 3)
3
```

Now I'd like to have a way to call the inside anonymous function from the outer one.

I managed to make it work by doing this but it looks complicated:

```
user> ((fn [x] (let [f (fn [y] (inc y))] (f x))) 3)
4     ;; good, 4 is the result I want here
```

Is there an easier way to nest anonymous functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's break that first line up:

```
((fn [x]
   (fn [y] (inc y))  ; construct an anonymous function
   x)                ; return the outer parameter
 3)
```

Note that the inner function is never used.

What you seem to want to do:

```
((fn [x]
   ((fn [y] (inc y)) x))
 3)
```

Comment: ooooh gotcha.  By wrapping the *(fn ...) x* inside a list I'm returning the evaluation of that instead of returning the outer parameter.  Why oh why didn't I think of that!  It doesn't seem like much but your answer helps me actually a lot!  Thanks : )

Answer (score 5):

I'd strongly recommend using the `let` form to improve the clarity of the code, e.g.

```
(let [f (fn [y] (inc y))
      g (fn [x] (f x))]
  (g 3))
```

I would even have the other function to accept the former.

```
(let [f (fn [y] (inc y))
      g (fn [h x] (h x))]
  (g f 3))
```

or even as follows:

```
(let [f (fn [y] (inc y))
      g (fn [h x] (h x))
      gf (partial g f)]
  (gf 3))
```

It makes the reading and hence understanding of the function much easier. Even with `let` I would not stop here and work on another better function.

After a bit of thought I think there's no need to define a one-arg function `f` when `inc` does that. Also one might get carried away using [the reader's anonymous function literal](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters) and the `let` form becomes:

```
(let [f inc
      g #(% %2)
      gf (partial g f)]
  (gf 3))
```

But the more I think about it, the less I understand the problem.

Could you describe what you really want to achieve?

Comment: what I want to achieve is understand better how the language works ; )

Comment: Hope you did with my answer.